# Загрузка картинок в List

Tags: изображения, android, java

Мне необходимо реализовать загрузку картинок в List. Вроде все должно работать, но из приложения вылетает.

```
public class MainListIllustrator extends ListFragment {

        protected ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions op;

        //String[] imageUrls={"R.drawable.one","R.drawable.two","R.drawable.three"};
        String [] images={"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZrajzoEXNlRWjMGE9L3kqI1EsFN9P5HCNhMo4xaqLkWuhAixo",
            "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQH7hisM_szjOKlVdQvq6m_J4lETkWxQOlAk3SMWs051TFFnmWMCA",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png"};

        @Override   
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,images);

            op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
    //                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
                .build();

            setListAdapter(new ItemAdapter());

            return super.onCreateView(inflater,container, savedInstanceState);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            //AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
        }

    //    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
    //        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
    //        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
    //        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
    //        startActivity(intent);
    //    }

        class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            //private ImageLoadingListener animate = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

            private class ViewHolder {
                public TextView text;
                public ImageView image;

            }

            public int getCount() {
                return images.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi=convertView;
                final ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_layout, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));

            loader.displayImage(images[position], holder.image, op, null);

            return vi;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: стектрейс выложили бы.

Но думаю, что ошибка завязана на строку

    loader.displayImage(images[position], holder.image, op, null);

loader - это из библиотеки volley? Но там нет метода displayImage.

Comment: Библиотека Universal Image Loader v.1.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется в стектрейсе у вас:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using
```

Так как не вижу у вас:

```
loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
```

Comment: ну это конечно посыпалось после того как я добавил:

loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

Comment: @sviter-pro loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));

Если вдруг решите перенести ItemAdapter в отдельный класс нужно будет ему передать Context например в конструкторе!

Comment: Простите за такую кучу глупых вопросов, ведь новичкам сложно по началу...А как сделать переход на другую ФрагментАктивити при нажатии на ЛистВиев????

Comment: @sviter-pro"ФрагментАктивити" не ясно, что вы имеете в виду, либо фрагмент, либо активити! На другую активити перейти http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity.html
Нажатие на пункт листвью http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/85-urok-44-sobytija-v-listview